# Concentration of electrolyte in rust removal

Tags: electrolysis

I will be attempting rust removal from a steel gas tank of about 5 liters by means of electrolysis, with steel wire acting as the anode.

For the electrolyte I've been advised to dissolve $\ce{Na2CO3}$ in water. Approximately what should the concentration be? Just looking for a ballpark estimate.

Comment: I've seen 4 grams per liter (roughly 1 tablespoon per gallon for my countrymen and the 15 remaining people in the world still not on the metric system).  You might find [Rust Removal Using Electrolysis](http://www.rickswoodshopcreations.com/miscellaneous/rust_removal.htm) of interest and/or helpful. Good luck!

Comment: The stronger the concentration, the higher the current draw.  I prefer to increase the concentration in increments so I keep current draw within the limits of my power supply. It's not a race.